# how to create custom vector maps with hoverable areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying something very complicated.
I want to create a custom vector map with hoverable areas (i.e. when the mouse hovers over an area, a small box with text apears).
I've been looking at jvectormap, but I honestly have no idea how to start anything with it, seeing as I know very little about JS and Python.
Most of the maps (including different areas I want hoverable) appear here:
http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Maps
But they are all in PNG format.

How can I take those maps, combine them into one map with the areas hoverable?
After that, how do I position divs next to each hoverable area that will appear onhover?

I know it's VERY complicated, if at all possible.

Also, seeing as I'm a freshman student with very little knowledge, I'm jumping WAY over my head here, but am looking for some extra grade credit.

Anyway do to this at least semi automatically?

Comment: It's complicated but not impossible. Your desire is not different than [this](http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall). You need to generate a SVG file with Adobe Illustrator or any program able to create paths and boundaries delimiters, and then use [the converter](http://svgto.jvectormap.com). If you want to define markers, you have to use pixel coords and not lat-long coords.

Comment: Thanx, that's about what I ended up doing. I used Illustrator to draw vectors on my map, then I saved it as an SVG file. The illustrator provided me with the HTML all by itself, so all I had to do was copy/paste it to my website and edit the CSS commands.
I then used a tooltip jquery plug in I found online to add floating comments on mouseover using CSS.
It ended up being less complicated than I thought it would be, just took a while to create the vectors.